# What is the running time complexity of the following piece of code?

Tags: c, algorithm

```
void foo(int n){
  int i = 1, sum = 1;
  while (sum <= n) {
    i++;
    sum+=i;
  }
}
```

What I feel is, the loop will terminate only if the sum becomes greater than the argument `n`.
And, `Sum` at `j`th iteration is: `S(j) = S(j-1) + j`

```
S(1) = S(0) + 1
S(2) = S(1) + 2
S(3) = S(2) + 3
...
S(n) = S(n-1) + n
```

How should I go further? I am stuck at this recurrence relation.

The loop will terminate when `1 + 2 + 3 + ... + j` times becomes greater than `n`. But I am not convinced, if it is okay.

Comment: Short answer: it's `O(sqrt(n))`

Comment: Please tell me, how did you deduce that?

Comment: No please don't. She should figure out her homework herself.

Comment: Gauss made this O(1) a long, long time ago.  The complexity of bad code is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

The classic way to prove this is to write the series out twice, in both orders ie:

```
S(n) = 1 +   2 +       3    + ...+ n-2 + n-1 + n
S(n) = n + (n-1) + (n-2) + ...+ 3    +   2   + 1
```

If you sum those term by term you get

```
2S(n)= n+1 + n+1 + n+1 + ... + n+1
```

With `n` terms

therefore

```
S(n) = n*(n+1)/2
```

(A result allegedly discovered by Gauss as a schoolboy)

From this it follows that it takes O(sqrt(n)) iterations.

Answer (score 1):

You have almost done it. The last thing you have to note is that `1 + 2 + 3 + ... + j` is `(1 + j) * j / 2`, or `O(j^2)`. This is a well-known formula from math (arithmetic progression).

Answer (score 1):

It will break after `k` iterations when

```
1 + 2 + .... + k > n

k*(k+1)/2 > n

k*k + k - 2*n >0
```

`k` will come to `k = (-1 + sqrt(1+8n))/2` (discarding negative value)

Hence, Time complexity is `sqrt(n)`.